# Multiple components match node with tagname app-lobby

Tags: angular

**the code was running fine on angular version 8.3.4 but when i updated it to the latest version of angular ( 9 ) i got the following error**

following is the stack trace

```
core.js:3866 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Multiple components match node with tagname app-lobby
Error: Multiple components match node with tagname app-lobby
at throwMultipleComponentError (core.js:5511)
at findDirectiveDefMatches (core.js:8276)
at resolveDirectives (core.js:8080)
at elementStartFirstCreatePass (core.js:14215)
at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14249)
at Module.ɵɵelement (core.js:14324)
at MainComponent_Template (main.component.html:1)
at executeTemplate (core.js:7562)
at renderView (core.js:7387)
at renderComponent (core.js:8577)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:836)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
at zone.js:897
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27769)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:611)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:517)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:502)
```

Comment: you added only error logs. Please add the code snippet also where you are getting the error. That will be helpful to give the answer.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've switched to Angular 9.0.0 and afterwards received mails from our users with the same error message. What makes things more complicated is that the error only occurs sporadically. I've never experienced it on my own machine and after the user reloads the app the error is gone for him as well. Regarding the circumstances, I also have a custom component I use multiple times in the template. I'm not sure if code samples will help as the issue probably isn't directly in the component or where the component is used but maybe timing related.

Comment: @beachovic yes exactly the same happening with me.
Although our team had found the solution but never got the reason why this happened . The same code was running fine on angular 8.

Comment: @shahnaz thanks for showing the support but i have found the solution.

Comment: For some reason Wasn't able to provide the code snippet here

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj, i would request you to add the solution. Will be helpful for others.

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj I have the same problem. What was the solution?

Comment: @Hernan Acosta there's no such specific solution . It was a hit and trial approach.  Some service was causing the issue . Still trying to figure out why the service was start behaving like that. Will update you if i figure out something.

Comment: Same problem except my multiple tagname component is 'button' :(

Comment: so, I just encountered the same issue when I tried to import a service into a component. nothing helped no matter what, started to blame on Angular 9, downgraded all packages to Angular 8, and voila, it told me exactly where the problem is, it turns out there was a null reference error in that service. So, Angular 9 is lying about the error, I'm switching back to Angular 8 compiler for now.

Comment: for us these error occurs only in ie11, but starts with the following error: Unexpected call to method or property access:
this was caused by disable within input --> replaced with readonly fixed it
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" style="width: 110px;">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="date" [min]="MinDate()" [max]="MaxDate()" (dateChange)="onValueChanged($event)" readonly>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false" [touchUi]="datePickerTouchUI"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

Comment: It's happening for me on the server and randomly! there is a way how can I reproduce it locally?

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same error saying `Error: Multiple components match node with tagname <my-tagname>` and I checked way too long that this tag is in fact unique. After reading over this question and all answers for the second time, I found @Eugen's comment to the original question and that finally helped me. So I'm adding this here with a little example in case everyone has this problem in the future. Angular's error message doesn't really help here.

My mistake was that I had injected a service into my component and used it directly in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.doSomething()
}
```

That doesn't work because it introduces a race condition between Angular's dependency injection and me wanting to use the service in the constructor. Inside the constructor, the service is not instantiated yet.

What you want to do is use that service after the constructor has been called, i.e. in Angular's OnInit-hook:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myService.doSomething();
    }

    // Rest of the component
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The two answers above about declaring `DatePipe` in `providers` should be considered. Today I met this problem (Angular 9) when adding an argument `private datePipe: DatePipe` in the constructor of my component without declaring `DatePipe` in the module's `provider`. After adding `DatePipe` in `providers`, I have no more the problem.

The constructor :

```
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I have a `SharedModule` which has my `DateTimePipe` both on `providers` and `exports` but importing it to my modules doesn't seem to work.
I had to provide `DateTimePipe` into my module directly.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That was also my problem. Added the Pipe in my Component's providers did the trick.

Comment: Same issue but pipe was missing on both `providers` and `declarations`

Answer (score 13):

This error actually has less to do with the tagname `app-lobby`.
I encountered this error when I applied multiple component selector on a html tag.

For example:
Component 1

```
@Component({
    ...
    selector: '[my-tooltip]',
    ...
})
```

Component 2

```
@Component({
    ...
    selector: '[my-button]',
    ...
})
```

Notice that both of them are angular component yet having a selector like attribute directive.

When you apply both of them on the same tag like below:

```
<button my-button my-tooltip="Some tooltip">Hover me</button>
```

Then angular complains about applying 2 components on a single tag. In this case it will complain about button tag, like:
`Error: Multiple components match node with tagname button`

The solution would be not to use multiple component selector on a single element.

Answer (score 11):

Probably you have **more than one** component with the same selector tag name `app-lobby`

```
...
@Component({
   selector: 'app-lobby',
...
```

Please double check to ensure that only one component selector tag name is `app-lobby`.

Comment: This answer should be considered.

Comment: I believe the author of the original post (and this is also my case) is experiencing this problem when there is only one component with that name in the selector. It looks to me like a bug in the incremental compiler or the ivy that maintain references to old versions of the same component

Comment: Yeah I just had to restart the dev build.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not directly related, but I got the same error in unit tests, where I was testing few of my components with Router using Angular 11. The error was
`Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname button`

This was super confusing since button is native element so it didn't point me anywhere. After a lot of struggle and few changes that I did to narrow down the problem, I found that the root cause for this was  `NG0302: The pipe 'formatPrice' could not be found!.`. I added the pipe and my tests worked again.

So if this happens to you while testing, double check if you declared all directives used in components that you have under test.

Answer (score 3):

For me following steps worked in a Angular 11 project :

1. First I searched for duplicate tag name across the project, found none.
2. Then I removed the line where the component was used and causing error.
3. Saved and Compiled it. Ensured that error is gone.
4. Pasted back the line. Recompiled and got a dependency error: xyz service not found. Added the dependency in app modules in providers array.

And that resolved the error.

Answer (score 2):

What was wrong in my case when I encountered this error:

I had another DI error (`NullInjectorError`). @eugen's comment on the question helped me.

**Tip:** See if you have a preceding error in developer console before this "Multiple components match ..." error. Usually such errors are reported only by JIT during runtime (when in **dev** mode), so you'll only spot them in the browser's developer console.

---

PS: Don't *provide* the `DatePipe` again in your own module as it's already provided by angular's [`CommonModule`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/59680c2644456f9d48b78e713f7f225dfb5bb289/packages/common/src/pipes/index.ts#L27). So check if you are missing the `CommonModule` import in your module.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was declaring in the test a mocked component with that tag and at the same time importing a module that declared the actual component. Removing the module fixed it.

Comment: In your answers, you need to be more explicit, also try to include code examples about how to solve the problem itself. If you see it is an old question and it was solved and you don't have more improvements to add, don't answer just add a comment or when you acquired the privilege you can editing the answer of others.

Answer (score 0):

@VikasBhardwaj
I had same problem in Angular 9 because I have created **lobby** page and **lobby** component. In this case, app-lobby is duplicated in pages and components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
```

So I have changed page name as lobbies, so the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by changing the component selector. But i guess the problem was inside some imported module, component or library.

As [documentation](https://angular.io/errors/NG0300) says, this error is caused by a repeated selector, but after checking several times, I was sure i have no repeated selectors (at least inside my project files) so the only option left is that my selector's name was used by some other component which I was importing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Angular 12 project (with Ivy enabled).
The selector was unique, but as it turned out, **I was importing the component from two different manners**:

- once from a relative file (e.g `import { MyComponent } from ./lib/my-component`
- once using a [typescript path alias](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353)  (e.g `import { MyComponent } from @my-library/my-component`)

So if in your **tsconfig.json** file, you have defined a path alias make sure to use it in every import or else you'll have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Another Possible Solution (2024):

For me the problem was that I imported the same thing (IonicModule includes IonButton) twice like so:

```
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, IonButton, RouterLink,
  ]
})
export class Step2Page implements OnInit {
```

I solved it by only importing IonicModule in my imports array, not importing IonButton

Answer (score -2):

I have an app in angular 9. I had similar problem, but then i realised that i forgot the provider for DatePipe. After that, this error went away... Maybe errors like these won't be happening after some time of angular 9 development.

Answer (score -5):

Add DatePipe in the providers.It will work fine.