# Multiple components match node with tagname app-shift-edit

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let x of createdBy;">
 <app-shift-edit></app-shift-edit>
</ng-container>
```

i am using angular 10 , I need to display  component multiple times in my parent component but it's throwing below error.
I tried to use ng-template with ngTemplateOutlet but still getting same error.

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Multiple components match node with tagname app-shift-edit
at throwMultipleComponentError (core.js:5442)
at findDirectiveDefMatches (core.js:8050)
at resolveDirectives (core.js:7842)
at elementStartFirstCreatePass (core.js:13810)
at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:13848)
at ɵɵelement (core.js:13923)
at ShiftsComponent_ng_container_61_Template (template.html:538)
at executeTemplate (core.js:7302)
at renderView (core.js:7111)
at TemplateRef.createEmbeddedView (core.js:10033)
```

Comment: i have unique component selector in my application .

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482442/multiple-components-match-node-with-tagname-app-lobby

Look at comment to the question in link attached from user Eugen.